# looping through checkboxes with POST and PHP

Tags: php, post

I know this has been covered indepth in other posts, but I can't get my var_dump of post to print out more than the last checkbox that is checked. it never outputs more than one checked checkbox, even though there is definitely more than one being checked

my html:

```
<form method="post" class="form" role="form" action="/users/teacher_account"    name="teacher_account_form" id="teacher_account_form" >

<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='subject_id[]' value=1  checked >Math</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='subject_id[]' value=2  checked >Algebra</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='subject_id[]' value=3  checked >SAT</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='subject_id[]' value=4   >
```

my php:

```
var_dump($_POST);

foreach ($_POST['subject_id'] as $subject)
{
     echo $subject . "<br>";
}
```

my var dump result:

```
array(2) { ["subject_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["update_button"]=> string(0) "" }
```

my erroneous foreach attempt result:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Have you tried using quotes in your html? `<input type="checkbox" name="subject_id[]" value="1" checked="checked" >Math</label>`? It *shouldn't* make a difference, but... Can you also post the form tag please?

Comment: So, `var_dump` demonstrates that the `subject_id` is not array, but a string.

Comment: Just a guess but you probably have another form element later on in your HTML with `name="subject_id"` (sans square-brackets)

Comment: @Revent just tried using double quotes ... no dice. now reposting with form tag

Comment: @Phil just checked html, don't seem to see another "subject_id"

Comment: @zerkms so what would it take to make it an array?

Comment: No JavaScript intercepting the submit event or doing anything with the checkbox values onchange?

Comment: Check what is sent by the client using chrome dev tools or fiddler first. Scientific guess: you have a checkbox with `name="subject_id"` (without `[]`) and with `value="6"`

Comment: @zerkms sorry but what do you want me to look at in the chrome dev tools?

Comment: @Phil there is no js manipulating the checkboxes

Comment: @zerkms the var_dump changes based on the rightmost checkbox checked

Comment: @compguy24: open it and check the network tab

Comment: @compguy24 - When you submit the form, you can go to the Network tab and see the POST data.

Comment: @zerkms it seems to be being sent: subject_id:1
subject_id:2
subject_id:3
subject_id:6
update_button:. that's in network->headers->form data. so not sure why its not showing up on my page

Comment: @compguy24: so now you see that the real name is `subject_id` not `subject_id[]`

Comment: @compguy24 I don't see any square brackets in that data. Are you sure your HTML is correct?

Comment: wow it's working now. i have no idea what changed.

Comment: Next time please supply complete information about the problem you're experiencing. Posting half of the relevant HTML and a PHP error that couldn't possibly have resulted from the markup you showed us is really just a waste of everyone's time.